# Android libgdx... moving of sprite back and forth horizontally

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I don't know what's wrong with this code. The sprite supposed to move at the to the left when it reaches the right end corner. but this code does when it (sprite) reaches the right end corner, the sprite just stops.

> The startM is the left end corner, and the endM is the right end corner

```
 //in constructor
 position = new Vector2(ShootingTreys.WIDTH*0.48f, ShootingTreys.HEIGHT*0.025f);

  // in update
 delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
 if(ps.touch == false){

        if(leftEnd == false && (startM <= ballMeter.getX()) ){
            position.x = ballMeter.getX();
            position.x += 20 *delta;

            if(endM == ballMeter.getX()){
                leftEnd =true;
            }
        }
        else {
            position.x = ballMeter.getX();
            position.x -= 20 *delta;

            if(startM == ballMeter.getX()){
                leftEnd = false;
            }
        }

        ballMeter.setPosition(position.x , ballMeter.getY() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make small change in your code.

```
if(endM == ballMeter.getX()){
       leftEnd =true;
}
```

Convert to

```
if(endM <= ballMeter.getX()){
       leftEnd =true;
}
```

And

```
if(startM == ballMeter.getX()){
   leftEnd = false;
}
```

to

```
if(startM >= ballMeter.getX()){
       leftEnd = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much, it goes left when it reached the right end corner. But when it reached the left end corner the sprite stops. How can i make the sprite go to the right again.

Comment: I haven't tried your code, may be if(leftEnd == false || (startM <= ballMeter.getX()) ) can be replaced by if(!leftEnd) and  why are you comparing boolean like if(b==true) instead of just use if(b) and for if(b==false) write if(!b) .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @AbhishekAryan

```
        if(leftEnd == false || (startM <= ballMeter.getX()) ) {
            position.x = ballMeter.getX();
            position.x += 20 * delta;

            if(endM <= ballMeter.getX()){
                leftEnd =true;
            }
        }
        if(leftEnd) {
                position.x = ballMeter.getX();
                position.x -= 20 * delta;

            if(startM >= ballMeter.getX()){
                leftEnd = false;
            }
            }

        ballMeter.setPosition(position.x , ballMeter.getY() );
```